# passing python variable to sql statement psycopg2 pandas

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I am trying to replace a piece of sql code with a python variable that I will ask a user to generate using a raw_input.

Below is the code i'm using which works great if I set `mypythonvariable` manually i.e. inputting `344` into the sql code, but if I set the sql as is to `mypythonvariable` it doesn't work.

The whole sql query is then converted into a pandas dataframe for further messing about with.

Any help on how to do  be appreciated.

UPDATE: I just added the `%s` code into the statement and i'm now getting the error message '': not all arguments converted during string formatting
'

```
conn = pg.connect(host = "localhost",
                        port = 1234,
                        dbname = "somename",
                        user = "user",
                        password = "pswd")
mypythonvariable = raw_input("What is your variable number? ")

sql = """
SELECT
    somestuff
FROM
   sometable
WHERE
   something = %s
"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=conn,params=mypythonvariable)
```

Comment: Not sure how the params are handled by pandas `read_sql_query` but you can just add the parameters to your string and pass it as a whole:

`sql = """SELECT ... WHERE something = %s""" % (mypythonvariable)`

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all that looked.

I found the solution.Looks like the params need to be passed as a list.

```
conn = pg.connect(host = "localhost",
                    port = 1234,
                    dbname = "somename",
                    user = "user",
                    password = "pswd")
mypythonvariable = raw_input("What is your variable number? ")

sql = """
SELECT
    somestuff
FROM
   sometable
WHERE
   something = %s
"""  
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con=conn,params=[mypythonvariable])
```